# How to concatenate two tables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am reading from two txt files. I have imported them into Matlab and did some calculations, this gave me two tables. Is it possible to concatenate the two tables into one? I am using version `2012b` and I have tried `join(LeftT, RightT)` but I get `Undefined function or variable`
Please see below:

LeftT:

```
1936
1937
1938
```

RightT:

```
5.4000    5.5000    5.3000    8.5000    8.7000    7.9000    8.3000    8.7000    7.5000    6.5000    5.5000    5.3000
3.6000    6.0000    6.7000    8.0000    9.7000    9.5000    9.4000    6.9000    7.6000    7.3000    5.5000    5.5000
5.7000    5.1000    7.4000    7.8000    9.5000    9.7000    8.9000    7.9000    7.2000    6.4000    6.5000    5.2000
```

Expected:

```
1936    5.4000    5.5000    5.3000    8.5000    8.7000    7.9000    8.3000    8.7000    7.5000    6.5000    5.5000    5.3000
1937    3.6000    6.0000    6.7000    8.0000    9.7000    9.5000    9.4000    6.9000    7.6000    7.3000    5.5000    5.5000
1938    5.7000    5.1000    7.4000    7.8000    9.5000    9.7000    8.9000    7.9000    7.2000    6.4000    6.5000    5.2000
```

Code:

```
LeftT = TableMin(:,1:13);
RightT = TableMax(:,1:13);

DifferenceT = RightT(:,2:13)-LeftT(:,2:13)
Results = Years , DifferenceT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the same data as yesterday, your data is not really in a MATLAB `table`. MATLAB has a specific data structure called [**`table`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html), but for your data you are just [concatenating matrices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html).

To stack matrices `A` and `B` side by side, use a space or comma:

```matlab
[A, B] % comma optional
```

To stack vertically, use a semicolon:

```matlab
[A; B]
```

---

To put the data into a MATLAB `table`, use [**`splitvars`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.splitvars.html):

```matlab
T = splitvars(table(LeftT, RightT))

% T =
%   3×13 table
%     LeftT    RightT_1    RightT_2    RightT_3    RightT_4    RightT_5    RightT_6    RightT_7    RightT_8    RightT_9    RightT_10    RightT_11    RightT_12
%     _____    ________    ________    ________    ________    ________    ________    ________    ________    ________    _________    _________    _________
% 
%     1936       5.4         5.5         5.3         8.5         8.7         7.9         8.3         8.7         7.5          6.5          5.5          5.3   
%     1937       3.6           6         6.7           8         9.7         9.5         9.4         6.9         7.6          7.3          5.5          5.5   
%     1938       5.7         5.1         7.4         7.8         9.5         9.7         8.9         7.9         7.2          6.4          6.5          5.2
```

---

To get the row with the max value:

```matlab
[MaxValue, MaxRow] = max(max(T{:, 2:end}, [], 2));

Year = T{MaxRow, 1}
Values = T{MaxRow, 2:end}

% Year =
%     1937
% 
% Values =
%     3.6000    6.0000    6.7000    8.0000    9.7000    9.5000    9.4000    6.9000    7.6000    7.3000    5.5000    5.5000
```

Comment: Nice! I have done just that. But the first column is being converted into a double. can the value display as in table?

Comment: @Fil matrix can only contain one data type, check the update to put it in a table which can support multiple data types (you can also look into cell arrays as another option)

Comment: thanks. works fine. By the way, can one look for a single maximum value in the `RightT` table and return the entire row of `[LeftT, RightT]`?

Comment: @Fil Sorry I'm a little confused by `RightT` and `LeftT` because your sample data actually puts `RightT` on the left side and `LeftT` on the right side. Do you mean you want to get the full row for the minimum year?

Comment: Yes! Sorry the tables RightT is on the right and LeftT is on the left as in your answer, only your labels are the other way round.

Comment: I am asking because it would be really useful if I could look a maximum value on the RightT and return the corresponding Year from LeftT. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Fil hmm I updated the answer, not sure if that's what you're looking for. First get the max per row (`max(T{:, 2:end}, [], 2)`) and then take the max of that to get the row index.

Comment: Wao.. that is exactly what i am looking for. Is there a reason why i am getting this `Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.`?

Comment: All works perfectly now, changing the `{` `}` with `(` `)` fixed the problem. thanks